# Find unique number for every group in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` that looks like this:

```
library(data.table)

group <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b")
start <- c(3, 5, 15, 22, 25)
end <- c(9, 11, 20, 23, 30)

dt <- data.table(group,
                 start,
                 end)
```

So, I have different groups and every group has multiple objects with start and end. Every row is such an object. Now I first (i) want to create a new column containing all number between start and end. I tried `seq(start, end)` and also in combination with `sapply()`, but I always get a list, that I cannot put in one `dt` field. Second (ii) I want to group the `dt` by group and get the unique numbers and (iii) count the unique numbers for every group  so that every overlapping number is counted only once. How do I do this :).
For example for group `a` this should be:

```
(i) new column (numbers)
        group | (old cols) | numbers
[row 1] "a"   | ...        | 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
[row 2] "a"   | ...        | 5  6  7  8  9 10 11
[row 3] "a"   | ...        | 15 16 17 18 19 20
...

(ii) new column (unique_numbers_per_group)
        group | (old cols) | unique_number_per_group
[row 1] "a"   | ...        | 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 15 16 17 18 19 20
...

(iii) new column (count_unique_numbers)
        group | (old cols) | count_unique_numbers
[row 1] "a"   | ...        | 15
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`base::Map` and `data.table::uniqueN` are great for this.

```r
dt[, numbers := Map(seq, start, end)]
#     group start   end               numbers
#    <char> <num> <num>                <list>
# 1:      a     3     9       3,4,5,6,7,8,...
# 2:      a     5    11  5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,...
# 3:      a    15    20     15,16,17,18,19,20
# 4:      b    22    23                 22,23
# 5:      b    25    30     25,26,27,28,29,30
dt[, count := uniqueN(unlist(numbers)), by = group]
#     group start   end               numbers count
#    <char> <num> <num>                <list> <int>
# 1:      a     3     9       3,4,5,6,7,8,...    15
# 2:      a     5    11  5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,...    15
# 3:      a    15    20     15,16,17,18,19,20    15
# 4:      b    22    23                 22,23     8
# 5:      b    25    30     25,26,27,28,29,30     8
```

If you really want a column with all of the unique numbers per group (that will be identical across rows within the group), then

```r
dt[, common_numbers := list(list(unique(unlist(numbers)))), by = group]
#     group start   end               numbers count        common_numbers
#    <char> <num> <num>                <list> <int>                <list>
# 1:      a     3     9       3,4,5,6,7,8,...    15       3,4,5,6,7,8,...
# 2:      a     5    11  5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,...    15       3,4,5,6,7,8,...
# 3:      a    15    20     15,16,17,18,19,20    15       3,4,5,6,7,8,...
# 4:      b    22    23                 22,23     8 22,23,25,26,27,28,...
# 5:      b    25    30     25,26,27,28,29,30     8 22,23,25,26,27,28,...
```

Comment: Congratulations, your `Map` solution is much faster +1. `uniqueN` appeared to be just more convenient w/o speed advantages, though.

Comment: I've seen bug reports for `data.table` that highlight that `uniqueN` is no faster and in some cases can be slower. I can't speak for "why" nor if there's a point at which it is faster (e.g., much larger sets? idk).

Comment: That's a point, cuttoff lies in between 1e4 and 1e5 rows, where `uniqueN` gets indeed faster (in this example)!

Comment: Though all 3 solutions work, I prefer this one. I have around 800k lines, so let's see which is faster :).

Answer (score 3):

We can solve this using `seq.int` in a `for` loop over the rows (these are fast in data.table!). We also `list` the sequences to get a list column. In a second step, we simply count the `length`s of the `unique` `unlist`ed nums `by` group.

```
library(data.table)

for (i in seq_len(nrow(dt))) dt[i, nums := list(seq.int(start, end))]
dt[, un_num := length(unique(unlist(nums))), by=group]
dt
#    group start end                  nums un_num
# 1:     a     3   9       3,4,5,6,7,8,...     15
# 2:     a     5  11  5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,...     15
# 3:     a    15  20     15,16,17,18,19,20     15
# 4:     b    22  23                 22,23      8
# 5:     b    25  30     25,26,27,28,29,30      8
```

---

*Data:*

```
dt <- structure(list(group = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b"), start = c(3, 
                                                             5, 15, 22, 25), end = c(9, 11, 20, 23, 30)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                        -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Though all 3 solutions work, I prefer the other one using only `dt`. I have around 800k lines, so let's see which is faster :).

Comment: So the for loop really slows this down, but `dt[, un_num := length(unique(unlist(nums))), by=group]` could be combined with the correct answer, if you wanted to compare it.

Comment: @gernophil For what purpose, `uniqueN` is surely faster with 300k lines.

Comment: Just wanted to point this out that it's in general correct.

Comment: @gernophil Aha thanks. Since the function also comes from the same package there's no reason not to use it and you have the best you can get ;)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way - I have used dplyr package:

```
# setup 
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

group <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b")
start <- c(3, 5, 15, 22, 25)
end <- c(9, 11, 20, 23, 30)

dt <- data.table(group,
                 start,
                 end)

# compute aggregate
dt <- dt %>% rowwise() %>%  mutate(numbers = list(seq(start, end)))
dt_group <- dt %>% group_by(group) %>% summarize(.groups = 'keep', numbers = list(numbers)) %>% ungroup()

# a function to merge values in lists
merge_lists <- function(lists) {
  all = c()
  for (li in c(lists)) {
    for (l in c(li)) {
      all <- all %>% c(., li)
  }
  }
  return (unique(all))
}

# creating unique list and count numbers
dt_group <- dt_group %>% rowwise() %>%  mutate(unique_numbers = list(merge_lists(numbers)), count_number=length(unique_numbers))
```

So, if you want to read more check:

- An overview of dplyr capabilities: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html
- rowwise operations: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rowwise.html
- group_by/summarize in dplyr: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html
- mutate in dplyr: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html

Comment: Though all 3 solutions work, I prefer another one, since I don't have to use an additional tool and it seems much faster using only `dt`.